# equation in matlab using newton

Tags: matlab

I have an equation `f(β) = cosh β cos β + 1 = 0` , and i need to use the βi roots to find some frequencies. The formula for the frequencies is

```
fi = sqrt((βi^4 * E*I) / (4*pi*m*L^3) );
```

I get this error and i don't know where the problem is

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in ==> C:\Documents and Settings\Laura Lupas\Desktop\subiect88\frecventa.m
On line 18  ==>     p= p0 - f(p0)/fd(p0);
```

Here is my code:

```
  function p = frecventa(f,fd,p_start,eps);

  p0=p_start;
  i=1;

  L = 0.9;    %lungimea grinzii in m
  b = 0.025;  %latimea grinzii in metri
  h = 0.0025;  %inaltimea in metrii
  dens = 7850; % kg/m cub
  v = b * h * L ; % volum
  m = dens * v;


  E =  2000e11; %modulul de elasti N/m patrat
  I= (b*h^2)/12;%mometul de inertie

  while(i <= 2)
     p= p0 - f(p0)/fd(p0);
     if abs(p-p0) < eps
        return
     end
      i = i + 1;
      p0=p;

      p = sqrt((p0^4 * E*I) / (4*pi*m*L^3) )
  end    



  % beta = 0:0.001:pi
  %f = cosh(beta).*cos(beta) + 1;
  %fd = sinh(beta).*cos(beta) - cosh(beta).*sin(beta);
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that

```
  % beta = 0:0.001:pi
  %f = cosh(beta).*cos(beta) + 1;
  %fd = sinh(beta).*cos(beta) - cosh(beta).*sin(beta);
```

Should be above the rest of your code, and uncommented?

So try this:

```
  beta = 0:0.001:pi
  f = cosh(beta).*cos(beta) + 1;
  fd = sinh(beta).*cos(beta) - cosh(beta).*sin(beta);
  p0=p_start;
  i=1;

  L = 0.9;    %lungimea grinzii in m
  b = 0.025;  %latimea grinzii in metri
  h = 0.0025;  %inaltimea in metrii
  dens = 7850; % kg/m cub
  v = b * h * L ; % volum
  m = dens * v;


  E =  2000e11; %modulul de elasti N/m patrat
  I= (b*h^2)/12;%mometul de inertie

  while(i <= 2)
     p= p0 - f(p0)/fd(p0);
     if abs(p-p0) < eps
        return
     end
      i = i + 1;
      p0=p;

      p = sqrt((p0^4 * E*I) / (4*pi*m*L^3) )
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `f` and `fd` are vectors that you use as input arguments to your function, you are likely passing in the updated parameter `p0=p` as an index into these vectors. Your code shows that you are calculating `p= p0 - f(p0)/fd(p0);` and later in the loop updating `p0` with `p`. This evaulation of `p` (and hence `p0`) involves a division step and is therefore not likely to yield an integer value result for `p0` . As this is the value for the index index into `f` and `fd` it would explain the error message that you are receiving, as clearly you cannot have non integer indices into a matrix or vector.